# TYPO3 - How to allow translated News appear without a Transl.Orig?

Tags: typo3, fluid, tx-news, typo3-9.x

I am trying to do my website very flexible for translations. Suppose I want to have a news article only in German, but not on the default language (English). How can I do this?

[image: Transl.Orig blank]

For example, creating a new News Article and leaving the **Transl.Orig** blank. However, this causes that in the frontend the news doesn't appear.

**Additional Info**

- Using Typo3 v9.5.1
- Using tx_news
- Bootstrap Package

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with fluid, you might want to remove the fluid tag and add the extbase tag

Comment: There is a news issue where there is some more information and where this question is mentioned: https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/815

Comment: I have used following extension developed by news authors, it extends ``Typo3DbQueryParser`` class function, here you can pass only tables you wanted without parent translation or for all tables,
https://github.com/georgringer/extbase_records_with_no_l10n_parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a good enough solution. We have a folder called "News Articles" where all the articles are being held. Inside of this folder I have added two sub-folders called "DE" and "EN".

[image: Two Folders inside News Articles]

Here, I am inserting their respective news articles (News Administration > *Folder name* (for example, "DE") > Create new news record). I set its Language to [All] (under the Language tab) - you'll notice that the **Transl.Orig** doesn't appear here.

[image]

**Note:** if you get an error saying something like "-1 is not a system language", it means that you have to configure the *config.yaml* file. This file should be located under typo3conf > sites > *your site* > config.yaml

Now, where the real magic happens is at Page > *the page where your news articles are located* > and open the news content element: [image]

Inside, go to Plugin > Settings > Starting Point, click the Folder icon on the left and select the folder "EN" (or "DE", depengin on the languange you are editing).

And that's how I solved it :)

Comment: That's a possible workaround, and you can still store news records in the parent folder which actually have a translation. Just use two folders in "starting point" and choose recursive=0. This might be interesting if you use a language switcher in the frontend.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this extension:
https://github.com/georgringer/extbase_records_with_no_l10n_parent

This extension changes the behaviour of Extbase to show also records without a language parent.